# create a json and post it to action method and use the data + MVC4 + WCF

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, wcf

I have created a JSON string as below and post it to my Controller. And I'm using WCF Service also

var inputParams = {
            Type: "xxx",
            Name: "yyy"
        };

```
    var url = '@Url.Action("Action", "Controller")?inputParams=' + JSON.stringify(inputParams);
```

### COntroller

dynamic values = WCFServiceClient.GetValues(jSerializer.Serialize(inputParams));

### SERVICE

dynamic inputParameters = jSerializer.Deserialize(inputParams);

this point I'm getting the result as :- {"Type":"Student","Name":"Ann"}

How I will get value of 'Type' & 'Name' ?

Answer (score 0):

Create Model class like

```
Public class YourModel 
{
Public string type{get;set;}
Public string name{get;set;}

}
```

// In your action

```
Public ActionResult yourAction(YourModel Model)
{
// Here You Can Access Your Values 
//Like 
 Model.Type or Model.Name 



}
```

Note:Remember one thing your model property name should be match with incoming stringyfy array

Comment: Instead of 'inputParams' as argument of my Action method I tried with 'YourModel Model' as argument. But all the properties of my model is coming as NULL. Another one question is If I'm doing like this, Again I need to construct JSON string for passing to WCF service ?? Please advice.